# Django: Change root url in application

Tags: python, django, url, hyperlink, navigation

I have a working application/system (Python 3.9, Django 3.1) on my server.
Now I need to move it to another server with an alias.

From this `www.myserver.com` to this `www.otherserver.com/myapp`.

In Apache2 config I have line `WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /path/to/myapp/wsgi.py`.
But now I have a problem with all links in app, e.g. link from index page to catalog page redirects to `www.otherserver.com/catalog` but I need `www.otherserver.com/myapp/catalog`.

- Is there any feature in Django?
- Is it possible to set just some global variable in settings.py?
- Do I need to edit all the links in the templates?

What is the best solution?

Answer (score 5):

A quick way is to include the projects url patterns at the new path.

Make a new patterns list, e.g. `base_patterns`

```
base_patterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('app/', include('app.urls),
]
```

At the bottom of the main urls.py include the `base_patterns` at the new path.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('catalog/', include(base_patterns)),
]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set this by adjusting the value of [**`ROOT_URLCONF`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#root-urlconf) settings variable. For that, you need to have two URL module

```
#project/urls/myserver.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('app/', include('app.urls'))
]



#project/urls/other_server.py
from django.urls import include, path

from .myserver import urlpatterns as my_server_patterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('catalog/', include(my_server_patterns)),
]
```

Now fetch the value of **`ROOT_URLCONF`** from the environment as

```
import os

ROOT_URLCONF = os.environ.get("ROOT_URLCONF", "project.urls.myserver")
```